# Cannot build and debug project using either Codeblocks or Qtcreator

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, cmake-gui

I am trying to build from scratch Mince on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 using an IDE(either Qtcreator or Codeblocks) because I want to debug the source, to understand how it works better.

Repository: https://github.com/Kingsford-Group/mince/

EDIT: since I found a workaround to build the project externally using -pthread I wonder if editing the file invoked by the `make` command would allow me to build from one of the IDE and debug the code.

I use `cmake-gui` with

```
BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: 
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince
```

and get this:

```html
Boost version: 1.54.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  iostreams
  filesystem
  system
  thread
  timer
  program_options
  serialization
BOOST INCLUDE DIR = /usr/include
BOOST INCLUDE DIRS = /usr/include
BOOST LIB DIR = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
BOOST LIBRAREIS = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_timer.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
Build system will fetch and build the Cereal serialization library
==================================================================
Build system will fetch and build Jellyfish
==================================================================
Found Intel TBB
TBB_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libtbb.so;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so
CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES = /build/;/bin/;/lib/;/external/;/src/obsolete/;/include/obsolete/;.git/
TBB_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libtbb.so;/usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so
Boost_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_timer.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
Configuring done
Generating done
```

Then I use `# make` and get:

```html
...
...
...
...
[ 67%] Built target minceutils
make -f src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/depend
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build"
cd /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build/src /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build/src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target canoncmp
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build"
make -f src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build"
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 71%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/CanonicalCompare.cpp.o
cd /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build/src && /usr/bin/c++    -DHAVE_LOGGER -funroll-loops -fPIC -O3 -DHAVE_ANSI_TERM -DHAVE_SSTREAM -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -I/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include -I/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external -I/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external/cereal/include -I/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external/install/include -I/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external/install/include/jellyfish-2.1.3    -o CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/CanonicalCompare.cpp.o -c /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp
In file included from /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include/MinceUtils.hpp:15:0,
                 from /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:20:
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include/ReadLibrary.hpp: In copy constructor ‘ReadLibrary::ReadLibrary(const ReadLibrary&)’:
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include/ReadLibrary.hpp:35:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             for (size_t i = 0; i < mc; ++i) { libTypeCounts_[i].store(rl.libTypeCounts_[i].load()); }
                                    ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include/ReadLibrary.hpp: In constructor ‘ReadLibrary::ReadLibrary(ReadLibrary&&)’:
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/include/ReadLibrary.hpp:48:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             for (size_t i = 0; i < mc; ++i) { libTypeCounts_[i].store(rl.libTypeCounts_[i].load()); }
                                    ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > parseReadFile(const string&)’:
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:37:7: warning: variable ‘isFastq’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  bool isFastq{false};
       ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:74:13: warning: unused variable ‘nb_threads’ [-Wunused-variable]
   const int nb_threads      = 10;
             ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:75:13: warning: unused variable ‘concurrent_file’ [-Wunused-variable]
   const int concurrent_file = 1;   // Number of files to read simultaneously
             ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:76:13: warning: unused variable ‘max_read_group’ [-Wunused-variable]
   const int max_read_group  = 100; // Number of reads in each "job" group
             ^
/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/src/CanonicalCompare.cpp:82:12: warning: unused variable ‘bucketStringLength’ [-Wunused-variable]
   uint32_t bucketStringLength;
            ^
Linking CXX executable canoncmp
cd /home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -DHAVE_LOGGER -funroll-loops -fPIC -O3 -DHAVE_ANSI_TERM -DHAVE_SSTREAM -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs    CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/CanonicalCompare.cpp.o  -o canoncmp  -L/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/lib  -L/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external/install/lib -rdynamic libminceutils.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_iostreams -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_timer -lboost_program_options -lboost_serialization -lpthread -lz -Wl,-Bdynamic ../../external/install/lib/libjellyfish-2.0.a -lpthread -lm -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lgomp -lrt -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN/../lib:\$ORIGIN/../../lib:\$ORIGIN/" 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(ptw-pause.o): nella funzione "__pause_nocancel":
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81: riferimento non definito a "__syscall_error"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81: riferimento non definito a "__syscall_error"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): nella funzione "__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal":
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:285: undefined reference to "__libc_setup_tls"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:303: undefined reference to "_dl_cpuclock_offset"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:419: undefined reference to "_dl_pagesize"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:428: undefined reference to "_dl_pagesize"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:448: undefined reference to "_dl_init_static_tls"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:450: undefined reference to "_dl_wait_lookup_done"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): nella funzione "__pthread_get_minstack":
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/nptl-init.c:471: undefined reference to "_dl_pagesize"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(pthread_create.o): nella funzione "allocate_stack":
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/allocatestack.c:475: undefined reference to "_dl_stack_flags"
/build/eglibc-MjiXCM/eglibc-2.19/nptl/allocatestack.c:614: undefined reference to "_dl_stack_flags"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/canoncmp] Error 1
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build"
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/all] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/build"
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I managed to link correctly and run everything by selecting the failing  command (i.e.

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/c++   -DHAVE_LOGGER -funroll-loops -fPIC -O3 -DHAVE_ANSI_TERM -DHAVE_SSTREAM -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs    CMakeFiles/canoncmp.dir/CanonicalCompare.cpp.o  -o canoncmp  -L/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/lib  -L/home/federico/bioinfo/Mince/external/install/lib -rdynamic libminceutils.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_iostreams -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_timer -lboost_program_options -lboost_serialization -lpthread -lz -Wl,-Bdynamic ../../external/install/lib/libjellyfish-2.0.a -lpthread -lm -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lgomp -lrt -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN/../lib:\$ORIGIN/../../lib:\$ORIGIN/"
```

and replace `-lpthread` with `-pthread` but since I wanted to understand the code I wanted to open it and build it using Qtcreator or Codeblocks and use the debugger this is not working.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT= Title, since I found a workaround to build the project externally using -pthread I wonder if editing the file invoked by the `make` command would allow me to build from one of the IDE and debug the code.

Comment: It seems that you have solved the problem that your post is almost all
about (Yes, `-pthread` is strictly correct, `-lpthread` strictly
is not) and finally mention a different one, namely that
debugging the project in Qtcreator or Codeblocks is "not working".
Please edit your question to focus clearly on the problem you
want solved. Bear in mind that "not working" is not a useful
problem description.

Comment: @MikeKinghan thank you. I hope that my issue is more clear now.